# how to make SeparatorMenuItem vertical?

Tags: python, gtk

how to make Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem() vertical as in the picture?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOZ7e.png

I use the language python

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What search plugin is that? I wouldn't be surprised if that's not even GTK+, let alone not using GtkMenu. (And I don't think multicolumn menus like that are even possible with GtkMenu, but I have yet to use GtkMenu so I don't know.)